# Is it possible to detect an ignored output of a Matlab function?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a heavy-duty workhorse of a function:

```
[a b c d] = lotsOfComputation();
```

In some use cases, I may only need one or two of its outputs.  In those cases, I ignore the output with a `~`.  Is it possible to detect this from within the `lostOfComputation` function?

(Yes, I know the more elegant solution is a refactor into separate functions. I have already done this for the immediate use-case, but the question remained in my head.)

Comment: MATLAB does have a way of detecting if an output is specified. The `hist` function is one example. Without an output, it plots a histogram. With an output, it returns the count of each bin and the bin spacing. You could try looking into its documentation to see if there's a way to detect an omitted output variable. (I'd do it, but my machine is tied up with an hours-long computation right now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, try [nargout](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html), it returns the number of output arguments. Well, actually that will work when the argument is omitted, but it will count ~ as an argument. Here's an example:

```
function [a b c] = test()
  a=0;b=0;c=0;
  disp(nargout);
end

>> [a, b] = test();
   2
>> [~, b] = test();
   2
>> [~, ~, ~] = test();
   3
```

So perhaps the answer to your exact question is no, at least not with `nargout`.

Comment: As you noticed yourself, it does not work for omitted output variables, which is what OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, not that I know.

However, if you are asking this to save potentially wasted computation you could split your function into sub-functions, but retain the general syntax in your original post using `deal`.

For example, if you always wanted `a` and `b` from `lotsOfComputation`, you could remake your function as

```
[a b] = lotsOfComputation();
```

you could then have two separate computations for `c` and `d`

```
[c] = cComp();
[d] = dComp();
```

you could then write your original functions as

```
[a b c d] = deal(lotsOfComputation(), cComp(), dComp());
```

If you wanted to ignore the output of `c` or `d`, you could replace the function calls with a null value in the deal function, i.e.

```
[a b ~ d] = deal(lotsOfComputation(), 0, dComp());
```

I know that this doesn't directly answer the question, but it might be of theoretical interest :)